# Sql server database transaction deadlocks; visual studio insert procedures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-deadlocks

I have a sql server database setup that accepts insert transactions from a visual studio application that is running using threads. Now the transactions are getting deadlocked and I have a workaround in that when the visual studio 2010 code detects a timeout, it will just reattempt to insert the data.
Looking at my text logs that I have setup, this is happening way too often and causing performance issues.
Some of the online resources indicate finding the offending transaction and killing it but if my application is dependent on the results obtained in the database that may not be an option. Are there suggestions out there as to how to deal with this. I am using the Parallel Taskfactory in visual studion 2010, so there are at least 1000 threads running at any given time?

some code to view: my insert code

Any ideas really appreciated.

sql table schema

```
Table PostFeed

 id          int    
 entryid     varchar(100)
 feed        varchar(MAX)
 pubdate     varchar(50)
 authorName  nvarchar(100)
 authorId    nvarchar(100)
 age         nvarchar(50)
 locale      nvarchar(50)
 pic         nvarchar(50)
 searchterm  nvarchar(100)
 dateadded   datetime

 PK - entryid + searchterm
```

stored procedure for insert 
so it does a whole bunch of inserts and relies on primary key constraints for dupe checking

complete table create

```
USE [Feeds]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PostFeed]    Script Date: 09/21/2011 11:21:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostFeed](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[entryId] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[feed] [varchar](max) NULL,
[entryContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[pubDate] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[authorName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[authorId] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[age] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[sex] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[locale] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[pic] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[fanPage] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[faceTitle] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[feedtype] [varchar](50) NULL,
[searchterm] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
[clientId] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[dateadded] [datetime] NULL,
[matchfound] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[hashField]  AS ([dbo].[getMd5Hash]([entryId])),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Feed] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[entryId] ASC,
[searchterm] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
 GO
```

I tried exporting the deadlock graph, could not get it to work so here are few lines from trace

```
Lock:Timeout    60468       sa  0X01    247 G01 sa  2011-09-   21 16:00:44.750   1:4557807  3463314605  .Net SqlClient Data Provider    0   0XEF8B45000100000000000000070006    22164   7   postFeeds    0  2011-09-21 16:00:44.750 1   G02     0 - LOCK    8 - IX          0   72057594075152384   1 - TRANSACTION 0   6 - PAGE        
Lock:Timeout    60469       sa  0X01    478 G01 sa  2011-09-   21 16:00:44.887  (7bf23fc490ce)  3463299315  .Net SqlClient Data Provider    0   0X3802000000017BF23FC490CE070007    17900   7   postFeeds   0   2011-09-21 16:00:44.887 1   G02     0 - LOCK    5 - X           0   72057594075152384   1 - TRANSACTION 0   7 - KEY     
Lock:Timeout    60470       sa  0X01    803 G01 sa  2011-09-   21 16:00:44.887  (379349b72c77)  3463296982  .Net SqlClient Data    Provider 0   0X380200000001379349B72C77070007    17900   7   postFeeds   0   2011-09-21 16:00:44.887 1   G02     0 - LOCK    5 - X           0   72057594075152384   1 - TRANSACTION 0   7 - KEY     
Lock:Timeout    60471       tdbuser 0X048D73EF643661429B907E6106F78358  93  G01 tdbuser 2011-09-21 16:02:41.333 1:14386936  3463346220  .Net SqlClient Data Provider    0
```

Comment: SQL is needed. Rough schema of the tables and the query(ies) being run that are causing the deadlock. What [isolation level](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/08/isoposter/) are you using? [Deadlock trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx), have you done one?

Comment: I have not specified isolation level and I think it is more pessimistic. Like I said I just repeat insert on a timeout.I have not set a automated deadlock trace and just manually check if any deadlocks occasionally and kill those. I will focus on reading up on these. Thanks

Comment: Your app is basically doing a boatload of inserts to the database and nothing else (not doing a lookup beforehand to check for existence or retrieve an id, etc?) to cause the deadlocks?

Comment: sorry, no it does the insert and if it gets a dupe error based on a primary key, terminates the transaction

Comment: You nee to get the deadlock graph then post that along with the **complete** `CREATE TABLE` statements for `PostFeed` and all other tables involved including details of what indexes you have on these tables.

Comment: ran trace and could not find deadlock; then why are my transactions timing  out at times..I will run the trace for a longer period and post back

Comment: Does anyone have any comments on using TABLOCKX

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same situation inserting a boat load of records with parallel threads.  To get around my deadlock issue I specified a table lock upon insert...

```
Insert dbo.MyTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Column1)
Values ( SomeValue);
```

I tried using lowel level locks but I still got deadlocks.  The TabLockX slowed the throughput down some but it still was a ton faster than serial inserts and no more deadlocks.